# How to get rid of xmlns=""?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I am trying to transform XML to xHTML using XSLT.

After doing this I get a `xmlns=""` attribute in all HTML tags(`<p>`).

This is my part of my XSL file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"
       doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
       doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you add more of your XSL? (Trying to understand why your `<html>` start tag is outside of an `xsl:template`.)

Comment: Also, what are you using to process your XSLT?

Comment: @DevNull yeah the HTML is included inside xsl:template tag...I just included it for information..I am using Xalan to process XSLT

Comment: You forgot to provide a complete (but minimal, please) example that would allow people to repro and understand the problem. Please, provide this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all your result elements to be in the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` then you need to put that namespace declaration on the `xsl:stylesheet` element so use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

       <xsl:output method="xml"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```